# Tomcat not starting in XAMPP

Tags: java, tomcat, xampp

I have installed java and trying to start Tomcat through XAMPP but it is giving an error:

```
"tomcat started/stopped with error, return code:1 make sure you have java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free........"<br>
my java path<br>
JAVA_HOME: D:\java\java-se-8u41-ri<br>
path: D:\java\java-se-8u41-ri\bin<br>
XAMPP TOMCAT<br>
D:\xampp\tomcat\catalina_start  giving this error<br>
```

[catalina_start error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW2vj.png)

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287667/tomcat-upon-xampp-doesnt-launch-for-java-home

Comment: Also you can take a look on related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587803/tomcat-service-not-running-after-installing-xampp